# Add single attribute without value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, sticky

I want to add an attribute on a div, something like this:

```
<div class='media' data-type-sticky></div>
```

Using jQuery, so i've tried this:

```
jQuery('.media').attr(data-type-sticky);
jQuery('.media').attr('data-type-sticky');
```

Comment: wrap attribute with quotes....`jQuery('.media').attr('data-type-sticky');`

Comment: .attr() takes parameters and parameters should be represented within quotes.

Comment: I have tried with and without quotes but not coming

Comment: Yes that was the answer a blank argument needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass empty string to attr value.

```js
$('.media').attr('data-type-sticky','');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='media'>Hello</div>
```